# Issue with C++, getting error quoting invalid pointer

Tags: c++

I'm totally confused with my problem.   This code works with CentOS 6, however when i'm using it with CentOS 8 with GCC 8.3.1 I get the error:-  free(): invalid pointer

With the code I have, it doesn't make sense, because i'm not using the free command or delete.

When I try to debug it using valgrind or build it with a debug version, the error doesn't show up, so it's hard to troubleshoot it!

Below is both the code I use to call it and the code of the function as well.

```
string value="thenewpasswordhere";
string bigone=encryptAndDecryptString(value,"encrypt");
// program crashes with 
//     free(): invalid pointer
// the line after the call is never reached, however
// if i use valgrind, or build with debug version it does return.



   string encryptAndDecryptString(string theString, string whichMethod) {
        string theResult = "";
        unsigned char ciphertext[128];
        unsigned char decryptedtext[128];
        unsigned char key[33];
        unsigned char iv[17];
        int decryptedtext_len = 0; 
        int ciphertext_len = 0;
        
        /* A 256 bit key */
        //unsigned char key[32];
        string key2 = reverseString("1234567890mamqmwnebrvthxjwjrjwje");
        
        strcpy((char*)key,key2.c_str());
        key[32] = 0;
 
        
        /* A 128 bit IV */
        //unsigned char iv[16];
        string iv2 = reverseString("4n5b6vd83ov0emci");
        strcpy((char*)iv,iv2.c_str());
        iv[16] = 0;

        if (whichMethod == "encrypt") {
            /* Message to be encrypted */
            unsigned char plaintext[sizeof(theString.c_str())];
            strcpy((char*)plaintext,theString.c_str());
            
            /* Encrypt the plaintext */
            ciphertext_len = encryptText(plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                                    ciphertext);
        
            theResult = charArrayToHex(ciphertext,ciphertext_len);
        } else if (whichMethod == "decrypt") {
            ciphertext_len = HexToCharArray(theString, ciphertext);
            
            /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
            decryptedtext_len = decryptText(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                        decryptedtext);

            /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
            decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

            theResult = reinterpret_cast<char*>(decryptedtext);
        }
        getLogger().debug("encryptAndDecryptString -> P13 (returning) -> %s",theResult.c_str());
        // the above line is in the logs whether the program crashes or doesn't, so i know
        // theResult is populated correctly
        return(theResult);

        // i've also tried return(theResult.c_str()) and it also crashes in same place.
    }
```

Comment: `unsigned char plaintext[sizeof(theString.c_str())];` -- This does not do what you think it does.  What is `sizeof(theString.c_str())`?

Comment: You'll have to choose a constant size for the local (stack-allocated) `plaintext` unsigned char array, or you'll have to dynamically allocate space for the string on the stack (like strdup), or better yet, use a standard container that will manage such things for you, like vector.

Comment: `sizeof(theString.c_str())` always returns a constant `sizeof(intptr_t)` of course. Note - `sizeof` is always a constant, have no illusions there, ever

Comment: `sizeof(theString.c_str()) == sizeof(const char *)` which is more than likely equal to 4 or 8.  *This code works with CentOS 6,* -- No it doesn't -- undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has at least one mistake:

```
unsigned char plaintext[sizeof(theString.c_str())];
strcpy((char*)plaintext,theString.c_str());
```

This does not create an array sized to `sizeof(theString.c_str()))` characters.  That `sizeof` line is equivalent to:

`unsigned char plaintext[sizeof(const char *)]`, which is more than likely

`unsigned char plaintext[4]`

or

`unsigned char plaintext[8]`

depending on the platform (32-bit or 64-bit).  Thus a memory overwrite exists if `theString` has a length greater than or equal to `sizeof(const char *)`.

---

The alternative is to create a `std::vector<char>` that is sized correctly, or a `std::string` that is sized correctly:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> plaintext(theString.size() + 1);
strcpy((char*)plaintext.data(),theString.c_str());
ciphertext_len = encryptText(plaintext.data(), plaintext.size(), key, iv, ciphertext);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.   I'm no C++ expert, but know enough to be dangerous obviously :)      Thanks Paul!   Your vector solution fixed my issue!